# handlebars: "capture" a piece of html into a variable

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

Here is what i'd like to do within a handlebars template:

```
{{#capture $str}}racing car{{/capture}}
i want a {{$str}} for xmas!
```

Intended outcome:

```
i want a racing car for xmas!
```

So, the captured/recorded html should be written to a local variable which can then be printed.

Any ideas?

---

EDIT: Use case
Ok, at first I just want to know if this is possible. I might try it and then do something else.

Still, here is a more elaborate use case. Still it is made-up, but seeing the exact thing won't add much value.

```
{{#capture $long_html_1}}
  <input class=".." name=".." value=".." />
{{/capture}}

{{#capture $long_html_2}}
  <select class=".." name="..">
    <option ... />
    <option ... />
    <option ... />
    <option ... />
  </select>
{{/capture}}

{{#if layoutVariation1}}
  <section class="layout-1">
    <div class="row-fluid">
      <div class="span5">{{$long_html_1}}</div>
      <div class="span7">{{$long_html_2}}</div>
    </div>
  </section>
{{else}}
  <fieldset class="whatever-something-else">
    <label ...>The label</label>
    <div class="box">{{$long_html_1}}</div>
    <div class="box">{{$long_html_2}}</div>
  </fieldset>
{{/if}}
```

I don't want to repeat the declaration of the two $long_html_X elements. I also don't want to make a separate template for each of them (or maybe I should?). And I want to reduce the amount of if/else handlebars tags, to keep it readable.

Comment: I added one. Is that ok?

Comment: @Charles, thanks for pointing this out. A number of my questions have been of the type like "Is there a bigfoot", where it's hard to provide a convincing proof/evidence for either answer. The "better don't try" or "why would you do this?" that people usually reply is probably the best answer one can realistically expect. I am going through my open questions just now.

Comment: @Charles, this being said: After I accept an answer on a question, will this prevent people from posting further answers?

Comment: @donquixote Shouldn't those strings be in the context object anyway?

Comment: @Sime, I want to define those (html!) strings within the template, not somewhere else. "really long html" is going to be real html, not just text.

Comment: I changed the use case again to show what the "really long html" might look like.

Answer (score 1):

You can use "handlebars partials" like variables.

**Partial templates**

```js
<script id="long_html_1" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
  <input class=".." name=".." value=".." />
</script>

<script id="long_html_2" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
  <select class=".." name="..">
    <option ... />
    <option ... />
    <option ... />
    <option ... />
  </select>
</script>
```

**Main template**

```js
<script id="main" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
{{#if layoutVariation1}}
  <section class="layout-1">
    <div class="row-fluid">
      <div class="span5">{{> long_html_1}}</div>
      <div class="span7">{{> long_html_2}}</div>
    </div>
  </section>
  {{else}}
  <fieldset class="whatever-something-else">
    <label ...>The label</label>
    <div class="box">{{> long_html_1}}</div>
    <div class="box">{{> long_html_2}}</div>
  </fieldset>
{{/if}}
</script>
```

**Rendering script**

```js
var template = Handlebars.compile($("#main").html());

Handlebars.registerPartial("long_html_1", $("#long_html_1").html());
Handlebars.registerPartial("long_html_2", $("#long_html_2").html());

var html1 = template({layoutVariation1: true});
var html2 = template({layoutVariation1: false});

$(document.body).html(html1 + '<hr>' + html2);
```

​You can check out a working example at http://jsfiddle.net/nUDf3/

Comment: This looks cool!
Just one question: Is the <script ...> equivalent with <template> ?

Comment: and will those partial templates be available globally in the app (e.g. with Meteor), like other templates? Or is there a way to make these "local" ?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know much about Meteor. But in handlebars, the compiled template is assigned to a variable, so you can set the scope of the variable to make it global or local. For the partials, I think they are all members of Handlebars class. Looking at the source code: `Handlebars.partials = {};`